# Yii2 выборка по json строке

Tags: php, json, yii2, postgresql

Вообщем у меня приложение, на фронте это ангуляр на backend это yii2. И мне надо сделать определенную выборку значений с условием по Json строке. Строка выглядит примерно так: `{"due": "2020-06-09T10:21:31.698Z", "status": 0, ... }`
Вообщем-то обычная json строка, а выборку я делаю так:

```
$filter = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;
$query = UserDictionary::find()->joinWith('dictionaryWord')
->where(['user_dictionary.user_id' => (int)$filter['user_id']])
->andWhere(['<=', 'workout_progress_card', new JsonExpression(['due' => (string)$filter['time']])]);

if (array_key_exists('type', $filter) && $filter['type'] != 'undefined' && $filter['type'] != '') {
    if (strcasecmp('kanji', $filter['type']) == 0) {
        $type = UserDictionary::TYPE_KANJI;
    } else {
        $type = UserDictionary::TYPE_WORD;
    }

    $query->andWhere(['type' => (int)$type]);
}

$query->orderBy(new Expression("workout_progress_card->>'due' ASC"));

return new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => false
]);
```

Ну думаю понятно я выбираю значение у которых время меньше либо равно тому которое я передаю, и вообщем-то проблема в том что я получаю пустоту, хотя у меня точно есть парочка значений которые я должен получить.
Я предпологаю проблема в том, что дата хранится как строка.
Вообщем можно ли как-то исправить эту проблему? кроме как перебирать полученный массив ручка форматируя приэтом строку в нормальную дату. Может кто-то сталкивался. Просто для справки БД PostgreSQL

Comment: что-то я не знаком с Yii, но почему-то у меня сомнения есть по поводу того. что это `JsonExpression` работает так как вы предполагаете. по моему оно просток кодирует переданное в json, хотя вам нужно сделать обратное

Comment: @teran Вообще я это нашел в документации по yii2, хотя там толком и не написано как правильно работать со строками json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё я придумал как сделать, правда пришлось изменить чутка систему хранения дат, но зато стало работать:

```
$query = UserDictionary::find()->joinWith('dictionaryWord')
        ->where(['user_dictionary.user_id' => (int)$filter['user_id']])
        ->andWhere(new Expression("workout_progress_card->>'due' <= '" . time() . "'"));
```

Вот впринципе рабочий запрос.